# Symfony/Doctrine Return results from multiple entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to return results from multiple entities?

Eg: Entity1, Entity2, Entity3, Entity4

Each Entity will have a column `title`. There will be a where statement on the title field to return the filtered record.

The entities do not have a relationship with each other.

I was thinking of putting it in the Entity1Repository but the filter will only filter records from Entity1

The only solution I can think of is to get the results for each entity and combine all the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can return results as array

```
->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

and merge it. [array_merge()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp)
Or entity repository.